# How to rewrite URL to match a server using nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm new to nginx. I have two projects, and the one is django web app which is running **localhost 8000**, and another is tornado which used to provide api service and running **localhost 8888**.

How do I config the nginx that redirects all the url requests(from 80 port) to **localhost:8000** but **/api** requests to **localhost:8888**(tornado app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `nginx` config file. Add a `server` block and use `proxy_pass` in `location` blocks to proxy (redirect) the request.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
}
```

Save it, and reload nginx.

`nginx -s reload`

https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

Comment: If  this solves your issue, please accept the answer.